# Interface between iOS and miniadsb (or other ADS-B receiver)

Tags: ios, interface

Here's a question the likes of which have not been seen before on stackoverflow :-)

I am trying to figure out how to interface a miniadsb gadget -- http://miniadsb.web99.de -- with iOS.  Or, failing that, I would like to interface any ADS-B receiver to iOS.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Michael

Comment: ADS-B is based on the GDL-90 protocol.  ADS-B out receivers receive this data, then rebroadcast it via wi-fi or bluetooth.  What I don't understand is the exact nature of the rebroadcast information, how to detect it / read it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly. Your question is how to interface hardware with software. As far as I know, the miniadsb receiver has no USB/bluetooth/whatever connection, it supplies a voltage difference which needs to be decoded by a digital signal processor and can then be forwarded to a computer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but this answer may help some people.

ADS-B data is broadcasted by hardware and received by hardware. Sometimes, software decodes these broadcasts and forwards them over the network to a "Virtual" Radar or track management system.  In the past, this hardware was very expensive but is now affordable due to new companies and the year 2020 mandate coming closer.  Here are links to easy ways to get ADS-B data to show up on an iOS device.

Device: 
https://www.uavionix.com/products/pingusb/

App:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/foreflight-mobile-efb/id333252638?mt=8